# highlighting based on term or bool query match in elasticsearch

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I have two queries.

```
{'bool':
    {'must':
        { 'terms': 'metadata.loc':['ten','twenty']}
        { 'terms':  'metadata.doc':['prince','queen']}
     }
     {'should':         
         { 'match': 'text':'kingdom of dreams'}
     }
},
{'highlight':
     {'text':
         {'type':fvh,
          'matched_fields':['metadata.doc','text']
         }
      }
 }
```

There are two questions ?

1. Why the documents with should query match are getting highlighted whereas documents with only must term match are not getting highlighted.
2. Is there any way to mention highlight condition specific to term query above ?

This means highlight condition for `{ 'terms': 'metadata.loc':['ten','twenty']}`

and a seperate highlight condition for `{ 'terms':  'metadata.doc':['prince','queen']}`

Answer (score 1):

1) Only documents with should query are getting highlighted because you are highlighting against only `text` field which is basically your should clause. Although you are using `matched_fields` , you are considering only `text` field.

From the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#matched-fields)

> All matched_fields must have term_vector set to with_positions_offsets but **only the field to which the matches are combined is loaded** so only that field would benefit from having store set to yes.

Also you are combining two very different fields, `'matched_fields':['metadata.doc','text']`, this is hard to understand, again from the Docs

> Technically it is also fine to add fields to matched_fields that don’t share the same underlying string as the field to which the matches are combined. The results might not make much sense and if one of the matches is off the end of the text then the whole query will fail.

2) You can write highlight condition specific to term query with [Highlight Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query)

Try this in your `highlight` part of the query

```
{
  "query": {
    ...your query...
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {
        "type": "fvh",
        "matched_fields": [
          "text",
          "metadata.doc"
        ]
      },
      "metadata.doc": {
        "highlight_query": {
          "terms": {
            "metadata.doc": [
              "prince",
              "queen"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata.loc": {
        "highlight_query": {
          "terms": {
            "metadata.loc": [
              "ten",
              "twenty"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: chintan....{'highlight':
     {'text':
         {'type':fvh,
          'matched_fields':['metadata.doc','text']
         }
      }
 }... This should highlight must query match of metadata.doc content  in text field or not?

Comment: I think `metadata.doc` values need to be inside `text` field in order to be highlighted, so _prince_ , _queen_  should be part of `text`, also both these fields are `analyzed` differently and as quoted the docs, it might not make sense to group them.